# How do I access a returned variable from a different function within a function?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have a function "A" that retrieves an integer value from a textbox in SSRS:

```
Dim currasm As Integer = Nothing
Function GetAsmCurrent(ByVal currasm As Integer) As Integer
    Return currasm
End Function
```

...and a second function "B" where I would like to use the value returned from function "A".

```
Dim lastsn As String = Nothing
Function GetSN(ByVal currentsn As String) As String
    Dim currasm1 As Integer = Nothing
    ' <------ Here is where I thought I could call the function ------>
    currasm1 = GetAsmCurrent(currasm)
    ' <--------------------------------------------------------------->
    If Not currasm1 = Nothing And currentsn = Nothing Then "NO SN"
    ElseIf Not currentsn = Nothing Then
        lastsn = currentsn
    End If
    Return lastsn
End Function
```

It always pulls a 0 in, instead of 1, 2, etc. depending on the assembly number in the textbox on the report page.

Comment: How does currasm get updated? You seems to be calling you function, passing in currasm but you GetAsmCurrent function just returns the value that was passed in?

Comment: Agree with Alan. I hope that's not your actual code in `GetAsmCurrent()`. That function is most likely where the problem is. Can you update that with some real code?...

Comment: Just making sure you know how `string = Nothing` works, that is true when the string is unassigned or "", while using `string Is Nothing` is true when unassigned, but false when ""

Comment: In addtion to the GetAsmCurrent method pretty much doing nothing apart from returning the exact value you've passed in, you've also declared it multiple times.  You shouldn't need the first line Dim currasm As Integer = Nothing

Comment: You cannot assign Nothing to a value type (Integer) that is not nullable. Even though you tried, it will be 0.

Comment: @Mary You can assign `Nothing` to anything, it's technically equivalent to `default` in C# and not strictly `null` (though it's functionally the same for reference types as their default value is `null`).

Comment: The code in `GetAsmCurrent()` does work, it pulls the value from a report item i.e. text box in the report.  The report item in the header has this code: 
`=Code.GetAsmCurrent(ReportItems!TxtAsemPart3.Value)`.  TxtAsemPart3 contains the dynamic asssembly number in the body, so this header report item pulls it in, sends it to the function GetAsmCurrent(), and then displays it in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private currasm As Integer 
Function GetAsmCurrent(ByVal currasm As Integer) As Integer
    Return currasm
End Function
```

This function will return the value passed to it, not the class level variable. The code will always seek the variable in the closest scope. Sort of silly to return what is passed. Again, as I stated in comments, a value type has a default value, in this case `0` and cannot be set to `Nothing` unless nullable. It is customary to use `Private` instead of `Dim` for class level variables.

```
Private lastsn As String = Nothing

Function GetSN(ByVal currentsn As String) As String
    Dim currasm1 As Integer 
    currasm1 = GetAsmCurrent(currasm)
    If Not currasm1 = 0 And currentsn = Nothing Then
        currentsn = "NO SN" 
    ElseIf Not currentsn = Nothing Then
            lastsn = currentsn
    End If
    Return lastsn
End Function
```

In this function `GetAsmCurrent(currasm)` will pass the value of the class level variable and return the same value. Might be easier to just say `currasm1 = currasm` assuming the 2 functions are in the same class. As discussed above currasm1 cannot be `Nothing`.

This will not compile `"NO SN"`. What could that possibly mean? Did you intend to assign that string to some variable? I will assume you intended to assign it to `currentsn`.

If you are calling this function within the same class, it can be a `Sub`. Any method in the class can access class level variables.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone, I was able to clean up the code and get it working.  I think the `currasm1 = currasm` was the major improvement.